# Apps>Menu>Basic 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: facebook, methods

I am hosting my pages on my doamain. I put the following info. When I go to view the app it shows 405 Method Not Allowed..Not sure what I am doing wrong.

*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can look at your apache logs, it will provide a more clear error that we can help you debug with.  Though a 405 error typically signifies a problem with the server and usually stems for a POST request.

Comment: Depends on your environment, if you are using shared hosting, you can often find it in CPanel under error logs.  If you are running a more dedicated host, you can look:
`code` /var/logs/

Comment: Checked that no logs.I put a free google sites version in and it works fine. wtf>

Comment: Are you using apache or IIS?  Check your .htaccess if you are using Apache.

Comment: I looked in my file manager, no log file. So I created one. I have yahoo hosting, So I will presume it's iis, but truth is I don't know.

Comment: I found another error Method Not Allowed
the url is www.sushiloca.com/sushilatespecials/
The requested method POST is not allowed for the URL /sushilatespecials/index.html.
Apache/1.3.33 Server at www.sushiloca.com Port 80

Comment: Have you tried renaming your html page to .php?  Some apache configurations don't like send POST to html pages.

Comment: Your a life saver...it's always the little things. It worked.

Answer (score 3):

The first page load a APP makes is a POST request.

Seems your server could be rejecting them.

Its worth checking the server side error log for further information.

Comment: This is most likely the issue. The initial request containing the `signed_request` from Facebook with the user and authentication information is sent as a POST.

Comment: Suppose I should of mentioned that :-P The first request is also Proxyed by Facebook and who knows what that Proxy does :-P In terms of parsing/investigating your content that you return to Facebook.

Comment: when I look at it on a normal browser it looks fine, it's just when I input it into facebook.

Comment: I found another error Method Not Allowed the url is www.sushiloca.com/sushilatespecials/ The requested method POST is not allowed for the URL /sushilatespecials/index.html. Apache/1.3.33 Server at www.sushiloca.com Port 80

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, it will most probably be a setting on your server. I had the same problem, my server didn't allow POST method on .html pages, changed my canvas page source to .php and all works fine now.

Comment: I also have the same problem here and I just renamed the file extension to .php then the page display properly! Thanks Nizer!!!

Comment: Yea, if you have uploaded a default or index.html file, renaming it to some server side extension like php should solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I have made the mistake 2 times of creating my site in html instead of using a scripting extension. For example, if you are running on a Windows server and coding in Visual Studio, it is tempting to just create .htm or .html files.  However, most web servers will not allow a POST operation to these pages. Instead, create .aspx pages, which will still allow you to use the same exact static HTML and JavaScript.  This solved my problem in both cases.